# Rename filename using pyspark XML connector

Tags: python, xml, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am looking to write XML using spark connector. I am able to achieve it but at the end it generate part files example (part-00000) I need to rename it to currentdatetime.xml in below code.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

data = [
    (
        "xxx", "VN", "Goods", "bIKE", "Ignition", "20100", "13000",
        "1.0", "IT", "2024-01-23T13:15:30.45+01:00"
    ),
]

schema = [
    "PartNumber", "PartName", "Transport", "Vehicle", "Engine", "MaxWeight", "CylinderCapacity",
    "MsgVersion", "SenderID", "SendTime"
]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

df_nested = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema) \
    .withColumn("GmfHeader", struct("MsgVersion", "SenderID", "SendTime")) \
    .withColumn("Product", struct("Transport", "Vehicle", "Engine", "MaxWeight", "CylinderCapacity"))

df_nested = df_nested.drop("MsgVersion", "SenderID", "SendTime", "Transport", "Vehicle", "Engine", "MaxWeight", "CylinderCapacity")

output_path = "/mnt/test102/xml_output/"

df_nested.coalesce(1).write \
    .format("xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "n1:Part") \
    .option("rowTag", "n1:PartMastInf") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save(output_path)

print(f"XML files generated successfully at: {output_path}")
```

Above code will generate a file in my storage account as seen in image
[image]
I am looking to create a xml with currentdatetime.xml and _SUCCESS should be removed from each folder. Please let me know any idea appreciate if it works on Pyspark.

Comment: You can try 
part_files_path = os.path.join(output_path, "part-00000")
current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
new_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, f"{current_datetime}.xml")
os.rename(part_files_path, new_file_path)
success_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, "_SUCCESS")
if os.path.exists(success_file_path):
    os.remove(success_file_path)

Answer (score 1):

The `_SUCCESS` file will be created no matter what. You can delete it using

```
dbutils.fs.rm('<data lake url & container>/test102/xml_output/_SUCCESS')
```

side note: Since you're running this in Databricks, you don't need to create the spark session.

For a more comprehensive solution that satisfies the conditions named in the first comment of this answer:

```
from datetime import datetime

folders = dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/test102/xml_output/')

renamed_file_counter = 1
for folder in folders:
    files = dbutils.fs.ls(folder.path)
    for element in files:
        if(element.name.starstwith('_')):
            dbutils.fs.rm(element.path)
        elif(element.name.starstwith('part-')):
            dbutils.fs.mv(element.path, f'{folder.path}/{datettime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S")}.xml')
```

Comment: Could you please help I have multiple part files I just need to change all the part files into datetime.xml. So if you have 3 part file 3 xml should be created for example 20240222 hh.ss.xml,20240222 hh.ss.xml

Comment: @anuj I didn't know how you'd want to distinguish the three files, so I added a counter to the end of the file name.

Comment: @anuj if you want you convert that to pandas df and write to a file.

Comment: @ARCrow I have update my question now files are coming in folder how does it work on multiple folders? . Each folder contains one part file.

Comment: @anuj I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pandas api in pyspark.

Code:

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
path = '/dbfs'+output_path+str(now).replace(' ','_')+'.xml'
```

and

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
path = '/dbfs'+output_path+str(now).replace(' ','_')+'.xml'
df_nested.toPandas().to_xml(path)
```

Output:

[image]

and

[image]